# convert number to the nearest multiple of 10

Tags: javascript, math

in javascript, lets say I got a random number 136, i'd like it to convert it automatically to 140 or if I got 124 to 120 etc or 24 to 20 etc..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Divide by 10 and round it, then multiply by 10.

```
var x = 136;
console.log(Math.round(x / 10) * 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just do this: ( Math.round(YourNumber/10) ) * 10